# mysqld won't start on another system (nor on the old) - no log files available

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, arch-linux

I just installed archlinux x64, previously I used a 32-bit Debian. The old operating system still exists (nearly) unmodified, as I bought new disks.

On Arch, but also on Debian, I tried to start `mysqld` with their respective commands. On both systems it just hangs until it finally gives up and reports failure.

I moved the database from its original location to another path a few months ago, because I was running out of space. I adjusted `my.cnf` accordingly:

```
datadir         = /mnt/media/mysql_db
```

`/mnt/media` is the exact same LVM drive for both systems. So I mounted it on the new system and it complained about some `mysql-bin.index` missing, so I copied that file from `/var/lib/mysql` (it assume it was created when I first ran `mysqld` with an unmodified configuration). After that it complained about other `mysql-bin.*` files, so I copied all of them. This is the only modification, I made to the original folder.

Trying to start again, the logfile `/mnt/media/mysql_db/hostname.err` did not even get touched anymore. I checked `/var/log` and any other location I could think of, but no file gets touched by mysql. So now the start commands fails but does not give notice to me why.

So I tried booting into my old system, but here same thing now. I deleted those `mysql-bin.*` files again, since they weren't intially there anyway, but it still failes and does not give any output.

Any idea how to limit my search or find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test this at the moment, but it could be a permission problem.

Make sure that the correct ownership and file permissions are set on the `datadir` and all of the files within it.

The `mysql` user should own the `datadir` and permissions on the `datadir` should be 700 (or `drwx------`). The `mysql` user should also own the sub-directories and database files within the `datadir`. Directories should have their permissions set to `700` (or `drwx------`) and database files should have their permissions set to `660` (or `-rw-rw----`).  This can all be confirmed with `ls -l`.

If any permissions are set incorrectly (ie: if you copied the files as root, root now owns them), correct them with `chown` and `chmod`.

---

To change the ownership of a file/directory to mysql, use the following:

```
chown mysql:mysql /path/to/file
```

To change the permissions on a file/directory, use the following:

```
chmod 660 /path/to/file
```

replacing 660 to the permision you want to set.

Comment: Yes! I changed the permissions for the new system, but forgot to revert them for the old. Now I can just chroot into my old system and start mysqld from there. Thank you for the idea.